# Display image from Postgres Database using python views.py

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, django-models

I have a table is postgres database and the table has a column name `castimage` with the data type `bytea`. I inserted image into the column with a query (it shows [binary data]).

When i tried to show the image in my HTML page it doesn't show.

Is there a way to display image in my page? OR should I change the field data type which I used to store Image?

**views.py**

```
def search(request):
    FormSearchMovies1=FormSearchMovies()
    image=Tblcast.objects.get()
    return render(request,"search.html",{'FormSearchMovies1':FormSearchMovies1,'image': image})
```

**models.py**

```
class Tblcast(models.Model):
    castid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    castname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    castimage = models.BinaryField()
```

**HTML**

```
<img src="{{image.castimage.url}}" alt="CastImage" class="img-fluid">
```

Comment: Why don't you use file field?

Answer (score 0):

You could transform image to binary data and store it in postgresql, to use it in src transform to base64. Or you could store image url and pass to image src.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use an [ImageField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ImageField) instead a BinaryFields unless for some reason you have not option. When you store images (or any kind of files) in the DB your DB size grow very fast, some hosting providers set limits in the DB size. Also, the operations are slower because you have to convert the images to base64 if you can render them in html.

Again, my recomendation is to use an ImageField and store the image in your server storage, in a CDN or in other place, but not in you DB directly. If you can't do that, try to convert the binary code to base64:

```
import base64
img_bi = Tblcast.objects.get(pk=1).castimage
encoded_img = base64.b64encode(img_bi)
# pass encoded_img to the template into a context var
```

You need to add error checks to that code ;)

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{ encoded_img }}" alt="my_img">
```

If you can't change the field to ImageField reconsider to store the image using base64 instead a binary field so you don't need to encode the image each time you serve the image.